# how to change the value of a dynamic arrays in java during runtime?

Tags: java, arrays

this is my programm :

```
public class Basket {
private Item[] shops = { new Item("1",1)} ; 

public void storeItems(Item it){

        if (arraysIndex > shops.length){
            resizeArray(shops);

        }
        *shops[arraysIndex++] = {it};
        *shops[arraysIndex++] = {new Item(it.getName(),it.getPrice())};

    }

    public <T> T[] resizeArray(T[] arrayToResize){

        int newCapacity = arrayToResize.length *2;
        T[] newArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arrayToResize[0].getClass(), newCapacity);
        System.arraycopy(arrayToResize, 0, newArray, 0, arrayToResize.length);

        return newArray;
    }

}
```

in the lines the I indicated with * I will get such this error :

"Array constants can only be used in initializers"

which I don't know how to solve the problem in java please advice me about it.

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply lose the curly braces:

```
    shops[arraysIndex++] = it;
    shops[arraysIndex++] = new Item(it.getName(),it.getPrice());
```

Also, there's a bug here:

```
    if (arraysIndex > shops.length){
        resizeArray(shops);
    }
```

Since array indices in Java start from zero, the  correct comparison is  `if (arraysIndex >= shops.length)`.

Also, if you're using Java 1.6+, `resizeArray()` could be based on [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29).

And, finally, you appear to be doing pretty much what [`ArrayList<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does -- why not simply use the latter and not worry about reallocations etc?